# Audit on changes to the running iptables configuration

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-audit

I'm aware of how to audit for changes to the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file in CentOS/RHEL 6 and earlier, but how do I audit for changes made only to the running configuration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following `auditctl` rule should suffice:

```
[root@vh-app2 audit]# auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -F a2=64 -S setsockopt -k iptablesChange
```

Testing the change:

```
[root@vh-app2 audit]# iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT
[root@vh-app2 audit]# ausearch -k iptablesChange
----
time->Mon Jun  1 15:46:45 2015
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1433188005.842:122): auid=90328 ses=3 op="add rule" key="iptablesChange" list=4 res=1
----
time->Mon Jun  1 15:47:22 2015
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1433188042.907:123): arch=c000003e syscall=54 success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=0 a2=40 a3=7dff50 items=0 ppid=55654 pid=65141 auid=90328 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=3 comm="iptables" exe="/sbin/iptables-multi-1.4.7" key="iptablesChange"
type=NETFILTER_CFG msg=audit(1433188042.907:123): table=filter family=2 entries=6
[root@vh-app2 audit]# ps -p 55654
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
55654 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
[root@vh-app2 audit]# tty
/dev/pts/0
[root@vh-app2 audit]# cat /proc/$$/loginuid
90328
[root@vh-app2 audit]#
```

As you can see from the above output, after auditing for calls to `setsockopt` when `optname` (the `a2` field) is `IPT_SO_SET_REPLACE` (which is `64` decimal per the Linux kernel source code) it was able to log changes to the running `iptables` configuration.

I was then able to catch the relevant audit information such as the the user's `loginuid` (since they would likely have `sudo`'d to root prior to updating the firewall) as well as the PID of the calling program.

Comment: It seems that `iptables-restore` cannot be caught by this rule. Any idea?

Comment: @youfu not sure, you might try to log all `setsockopt` temporarily while you do it so you know what it's setting it's arguments at. There also may be documentation somewhere on what the possible arguments are. I also don't know how the introduction of BPF affects this advice. (this answer is like five years old).

Comment: Recent distros ship nftables-based iptables, so apparently IPT_SO_* are not in use.