# Debian 8 - IPTables reverts to state on every packet

Tags: debian, iptables

**Problem:** `iptables` cannot be changed.
On my computer, I can run `iptables -F`. `iptables -L` shows it is flushed.

When any packets come into or out of the machine, all rules are back! The same behaviour happens if I do a `iptables-restore < new_settings`. They are there for a second, but once a packet comes through `iptables` it reverts.

I'm using **debian 8** the OS was an upgrade from **debian 7**. It is someone else's computer originally.

What I've checked, thinking it would be one of these things:

- `iptables-persistent` isn't present
- `/etc/iptables/` does not exist
- When I look at `systemctl` processes there isn't even anything with `ip` in it's name

`/# systemctl --all | grep ip
run-rpc_pipefs.mount loaded    active   mounted   /run/rpc_pipefs
systemd-initctl.socket loaded    active   listening /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe`

- There is no `# firewalld` on the system.

Where can we find services or something that is changing system configs?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use `audit`.  Fedora enables it by default, and it floods the journal with NETFILTER_CFG lines.

See this question:

[Audit on changes to the running iptables configuration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206891/audit-on-changes-to-the-running-iptables-configuration)

In the example shown, the relevant process is `iptables`, which may not be very helpful.  However it also records `ppid`, the parent process (as well as the obvious `pid`).

In case the parent process *also* exits immediately...

You could easily use process accounting (`acct` package) to track the names of every exiting process (`lastcomm` command).  However that's less information than you might think.  I'm thinking of "bash" here.

It might be better to run `fatrace` to track opened files, which includes program execution.  Just don't try to pipe it e.g. through grep - it will fail to generate any output, I don't know why.

There's also a [page on `execsnoop`](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-07-28/execsnoop-for-linux.html).  If you can use that program, or any of the alternatives it suggests, that would be the easiest to interpret.

Technically I haven't allowed for `fork()`.  But I can't think of a good reason why you would `fork()` without `exec()` in order to create netfilter rules.

Comment: Thank you for trying! The issue I was having is I wasn't sure which file was being opened (like with `Fat Trace`). Also the iptables process was always running and difficult to see when something odd was happening because it was dealing with a fair bit of traffic.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** when you're having strange problems with config files changing all the time check your `/etc/network/if-*.d` files, if you've already checked `systemd` configs.

Turns out another option for where something can change the `iptables` command (or really anything) is in the `if-up.d` or `if-down.d` folders which deal make changes based on internet connectivity.

In `/etc/network/` there was a folder for both `if-pre-up.d`, `if-up.d`, etc.

Each contains a set of scripts to run when the `if-*` condition is met. So whenever internet connections changed (which seemed to be any change in the `iptables`) it would run a script which `/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables` which reset the iptables with the file `iptables` in `/etc/network/`.